# How to open one or more new instance(s) of the QMainWindow App in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt6

I have my QMainWindow set up as the code below shows. I have my menu include "New" and "Quit" menu items (see the image). I successfully coded the Quit one, which was too easy for me. All I want is to open a new instance of my main application when I click the "New" menu item (shown in the image).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYM9e.png)

```
class MainApp(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.show()

        self.action_Quit.triggered.connect(self.exit_app)

    def exit_app(self):
        self.close()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
MainWindow = MainApp()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: You can have only one QApplication instance which manages windows and events. However, you can create multiple QWindows within one application. Depending on your goal, if you want another window within one application, instantiate new QWindow. If you want new instance of the entire application then start a new process e.g. using `subprocess.run`

Comment: @warownia1 QWindow is the class that represents the window in the OS. You probably meant QWidget.

Comment: Maybe, I haven't used Qt since version 4, I don't remember all those classes involved in windowing.

Comment: Also, from what I remember, it's typically not a good idea to extend Qt classes unless you really mean to implement custom widget/window etc. For regular use, composition is preferred.

Comment: @warownia1 QWindow was introduced in Qt5 as an abstraction layer with the OS, in Qt4 there was no such API. The subclassing you see in the OP is the standard approach for creating QWidget subclasses with the UI created in Designer. Besides, subclassing is the only practical way to override methods and event handlers (unless using event filters), and is a completely acceptable practice - as it was in Qt4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a new window is just a matter of creating a new instance of it (which is the class of `self` if you want to create a new instance of the same type).

The actual issue is keeping references of those windows. If you create a new window without keeping a persistent reference to it, it will be probably destroyed due to the garbage collection of Python (or because no C++ reference is kept, which usually means using a parent QObject).

If you plan to have multiple windows of the same type, you need to use a *common* container. To achieve this, there are multiple solutions, but the concept remains: you need a "controller" that can always have pointers to those windows.

For complex applications, this usually means that the "controller" is a *main* object that normally exists within the program itself. A common way to do so is by subclassing QApplication and create a data container (even a basic python list) that keeps track of the windows.

A simpler solution could use a list of those window as a *class attribute* of the window class itself.

In the following example, the `CommonWindow` class has a list set as class attribute that keeps track of the existing windows and eventually adds/removes them when they're created or closed. For explanation reasons, I implemented a basic QListWidget that will be constantly updated with the current list of existing windows, adding them when new windows are created, and removing them when they're closed.

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class CommonWindow(QMainWindow):
    winIndex = 0
    siblingWindows = []
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # note: this sets a *class* attribute that always increases the count
        CommonWindow.winIndex += 1

        self.setWindowTitle('Window {}'.format(self.winIndex))
        self.siblingWindows.append(self)

        menu = self.menuBar().addMenu('File')
        newAction = menu.addAction('New window')
        quitAction = menu.addAction('Quit')

        self.windowList = QListWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.windowList)

        newAction.triggered.connect(self.newWindow)
        quitAction.triggered.connect(QApplication.quit)

        if len(self.siblingWindows) == 1:
            # avoid unnecessary calls
            self.updateWindowList()

    def newWindow(self):
        new = CommonWindow()
        new.show()
        for win in self.siblingWindows:
            win.updateWindowList()

    def updateWindowList(self):
        self.windowList.clear()
        for win in self.siblingWindows:
            self.windowList.addItem(win.windowTitle())

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.siblingWindows.remove(self)
        for win in self.siblingWindows:
            win.updateWindowList()


app = QApplication([])
test = CommonWindow()
test.show()
app.exec()
```

Comment: Thank you, I think I now get it.
I will be giving it a try but I got the reason behind the issues I was facing!

Comment: @gabrsafwat You're welcome. Remember that if an answer solves your issue you should mark it as accepted by clicking the gray tick mark on its left.

Comment: I did mark it as accepted, thank you for the heads up ;)